# How to calculate the greatest value variable can be stored in C#?

Tags: c#, variables

What's the simplest way to calculate biggest value variable can store in C#?

INT64 and UINT64 are the same in the range, but accept a different biggest value.
For example:

```
      UInt64 mm1 = (UInt64)Math.Pow(2, 64) -1;

      Int64  mm2 = (Int64) Math.Pow(2, 32) -1;
```

Is there a simple way to calculate the maximum?

Comment: `.MaxValue` property?

Comment: [`BigInteger`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.biginteger?view=net-6.0) has biggest value(infinitely large)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the following:

```
UInt64 maxUInt64 = ~0UL;              //  invert all bits 0->1
Int64 maxInt64   = ~0L ^ (1L << 63);  //  invert top-most bit
                                      //  equivalent to  (Int64)(~0UL >> 1)
Console.WriteLine($"maxUInt64 {maxUInt64}");
Console.WriteLine($"          {UInt64.MaxValue}");
Console.WriteLine($"maxInt64  {maxInt64}");
Console.WriteLine($"          {Int64.MaxValue}");
```

Output:

```
maxUInt64 18446744073709551615
          18446744073709551615
maxInt64  9223372036854775807
          9223372036854775807
```